# Derivative, the tangent line $y = \sqrt{9-4x}$ at point (-4,5)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The function is given,
$$y=\sqrt{9-4x}$$

Now I have to find the tangent line at point (-4,5).

This is how i did it previously...
[Derivative; The Tangent line $y=x^2 -4x -5 ; (-2,7)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080880/derivative-the-tangent-line-y-x2-4x-5-2-7)

Now, I think I'm getting mixed or something...

This is what I did so far:

$$$$

$$f(x)=\sqrt{9-4x}\\f(x_1)=\sqrt{9-4x_1}\\f(x_1+\Delta x) = \sqrt{9-4(x_1+\Delta x})$$

$$$$
So,

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} {f(x_1+\Delta x) - f(x_1) \over \Delta x}
\\=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} {\sqrt{9-4(x_1 +\Delta x)} - \sqrt{9-4x_1}\over \Delta x}
\\=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}{\sqrt{9-4x_1-4\Delta x -9 +4x_1}\over \Delta x}
\\=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}{\sqrt{-4\Delta x} \over \Delta x}$$

Now, I tried doing,

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} {\sqrt{-4\Delta x}\over\sqrt {\Delta x^2}}$$

I'm not sure if it's right, but I can't get it to work.

Any help??

Thanks

Comment: $$\sqrt{9-4(x_1 +\Delta x)} - \sqrt{9-4x_1} \neq \sqrt{9-4x_1-4\Delta x -9 +4x_1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} {\sqrt{9-4(x_1 +\Delta x)} - \sqrt{9-4x_1}\over \Delta x}
> \\ \neq \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}{\sqrt{9-4x_1-4\Delta x -9 +4x_1}\over \Delta x}$$

You made the mistake of taking the difference of two roots and making it the square root of the difference. But $$\sqrt a - \sqrt b \neq \sqrt{a-b}$$

Let's go back to the following line: $$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} {\sqrt{9-4(x_1 +\Delta x)} - \sqrt{9-4x_1}\over \Delta x}$$ Multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the numerator, which gives you a difference of squares in the numerator.

$$\begin{align} \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} {f(x_1+\Delta x) - f(x_1) \over \Delta x}
& =\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} {\sqrt{9-4(x_1 +\Delta x)} - \sqrt{9-4x_1}\over \Delta x}\\ \\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\;\; \frac{(9-4x_1 - 4\Delta x) - (9-4x_1)}{\Delta x (\sqrt{9-4x_1+4 \Delta x} + \sqrt{9-4x_1})}\\ \\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac {-4}{\sqrt{9-4x_1 + 4\Delta x} + \sqrt{9-4x_1}}\\ \\
&=  \frac {-4}{2\cdot\sqrt{9-4x_1}}\\ \\
&= \frac {-2}{\sqrt{9-4x_1}}\end{align} $$

Now evaluate the result at $x_1 = -4$. Doing so will give you the slope $m$ of the line tangent at $(-4, 5)$. Using point slope form, that gives us the equation of the line $$y - 5 = m(x +4)$$

Comment: Yes! Thank you! The answer I was looking for!!

Comment: You're welcome, didgocks!

Answer (score 0):

hint: $$f(x)=\sqrt{9-4x}$$ then we can write $$f(x)=(9-4x)^{1/2}$$ and the first derivative by the power and chaine rule is given by $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(9-4x)^{-1/2}(-4)$$ thus we get $$f'(x)=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{9-4(-4)}}=-\frac{2}{5}$$ and the tangent line is given by $$y=-\frac{2}{5}x+n$$ and for $x=-4$ we get $n=\frac{17}{4}$
for the first derivative with the definition see here
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{9-4(x+h)}-\sqrt{9-x}}{h}=\frac{-4}{\sqrt{9-4(x+h)}+\sqrt{9-4x}}$$ and the limit for $h->0$ is given by $\frac{-2}{\sqrt{9-4x}}$

Comment: I think the OP is using (or needing to use) the definition of derivative.

Comment: Yes, I have don't know what it is

Comment: @didgocks so you don't know why we take derivative to find the slope of tangents at that point.

Comment: ... and the post of mine

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating the equation wrt. $x$  gives the slope at any $x$ on the curve, and if $y=\sqrt{9-4x}$,

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{d\sqrt{9-4x}}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{9-4x}}\cdot\dfrac{d(9-4x)}{dx}$

$\implies \dfrac{-4}{2\sqrt{9-4x}}=\dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{9-4x}}$

Putting, $x=-4$, The slope comes out to be, $\dfrac{-2}{5}.$

Using, $(y-y_1)=m(x-x_1)$, The equation of the line comes out to be,

$(y-5)=\dfrac{-2}{5}(x-(-4))$

$\implies 2x+5y-17=0$

Comment: The OP is needing to use the definition of the derivative at a point.

Comment: @didgocks [This](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.khanacademy.org%2Fmath%2Fdifferential-calculus%2Ftaking-derivatives%2Fderivative_intro%2Fv%2Fcalculus-derivatives-1-new-hd-version&ei=3X2hVPmRIIyjugSEyoDYCQ&usg=AFQjCNHUzVj0G9UHp2z1drRRdqBjjBX50g&sig2=4jDWym6e-GjRRXaEDa5HLw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E) Khanacadamy video can give you some intuition.